# Autohotkey: Scrape text from window (LOTRO)

Tags: automation, autohotkey, mmo, online-game

I am fairly advanced with my LOTRO scripting, but sadly, have not figured out a way to capture data from the chatbox.  I am trying to write an external mapping application and would like to have autohotkey automatically grab data from the screen, particularly the location data that has the heading, by typing:

```
/loc
```

inside of the chat box.

This image is linked to imgur with the areas I am trying to capture highlighted.
[image]

I find it very odd as I can highlight the text in the window easily, and copy and paste it to notepad or any other wordpad editor.

I have tried to following methods to attempt to gather the text from the window, but I cannot seem to find any controls or text, even when running the script as administrator.

```
WinGet, cList, ControlList, A
Loop, Parse, cList, `n, `r
{
  ControlGetText, cText, % A_LoopField, A
  if cText
    res.="Control: " A_LoopField "`tText: " cText "`n"
}
MsgBox % res

WinGetText, text  ; The window found above will be used.
MsgBox, The text is:`n%text%
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Games have non conventional GUIs and you can't just get there controls and use them.

For getting information from screen for nonconventional GUIs you can use following commands: [ImageSearch](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm), [PixelGetColor](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/PixelGetColor.htm), [PixelSearch](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/PixelSearch.htm).

You can also try to get information from registry (maybe information that you need is stored in registry) with [RegRead](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/RegRead.htm) command.

Some information can be stored in text files and you can read them with [FileRead](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/FileRead.htm), [FileReadLine](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/FileReadLine.htm), [LoopReadFile](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/LoopReadFile.htm).

Also you can try to get information from memory. For scripts and guides about reading memory with AutoHotkey just google "AutoHotkey read memory".

Also be aware of [that](https://www.google.ge/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=game%20screenshot%20hidden%20watermarks).

Comment: I have found a way to gather it by running a chatog command that outputs a txt file then I have autohotkey read that text file.  It's cumbersome, but it works.

Comment: I can get my bearing location from memory, I found the address that stores that, it's just super weird that I can't find a memory location that holds your coordinates.  Apparently it doesn't exist.

I will mark this as the answer due to it being very comprehensive.

I used cheatengine to find the memory location, and read the text file for coordinates, not the best solution but it works :(